# What is the meaning of to 'gain one's ends'?

Tags: meaning

I was reading a paragraph which quoted Johann Von Goethe. It said:

> The only means to ***gain one’s ends with people*** are force and cunning. Love also, they say;
>   but that is to wait for sunshine, and life needs every moment.

I tried searching on google but could not find its meaning.

And also, could you please explain its meaning? What is the meaning of **"wait for sunshine"** and  **"life needs every moment"**?

Comment: *gain one's ends = **achieve one's goals***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage must have been translated from the German, probably some time ago.

*End* in this context is an old-fashioned term for a purpose or objective. I suppose the meaning is that, if you wait until you can achieve your purpose through love, you may have to wait a long time (sunny days not always being common in northern Europe) and life is too short to wait.